# How to get ID from the relationship table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hi i have 2 tables Numbers and number_details with 2 models Number and Number_details. And in this is my code

Number model

```
 public function number_details()
{
    return $this->hasOne('number_id','id');
}
```

NumberDetails Model

```
public function number() {
    return $this->hasOne('Number');
}
```

NumberController

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $numberDetails = new NumberDetails;
    $numberDetails->number_id =//how to get id ;
    $numberDetails->save();
}
```

Comment: Please illustrate your problem by adding proper details. Like why do you want get number_id ? If you want it to create the record NumberDetails, then you can send it in the request and access it using $request->number_id;

Comment: I want to get numbr_id and store in DB i want every number has own number_details

Comment: You can easily send it with the request that is calling the store method... 
Its a pretty basic question even newbies who understand the basic working of laravel must know how to get this done. If you are still not following then I recommend you to follow some tutorial and make a sample application.

Comment: This is not useful answer, but thank you!

Comment: Well, if it was not useful then I am really sorry. You should take criticism in constructive manner. One day when you will learn the basics of how web applications work (I hope) then you will understand how dumb was your question. :) Also, people can help you, give you advice, show you the right path but you are the one who have to walk on that path. No one is gonna do your part of work only if you are saying it on stackoverflow. I hope this answer will be better then earlier one. Cheers :)

Comment: In another method i save user ID in db 
$number->user_id = $user = \Auth::user()->id;

but this is for authenticated user by when i try to get number ID in my numberDetails store method $numberDetails->number_id = Number::find(id); i have an error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I resolve my problem Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: when i try to use :

```
 $numberDetails->number_id = Number::find(id);  Trying to get property of non-object
```